# PHP JSON Specific Key To Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to bring back just selectionId's and place them in an array from my json response, but I just can't manage it. I have my json response as

```
[
{
marketId: "1.133102670",
marketName: "2m Hrd",
totalMatched: 39556.86,
runners: [
{
selectionId: 13764229,
runnerName: "Kereman",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 1
},
{
selectionId: 11378898,
runnerName: "City Dreamer",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 2
},
{
selectionId: 12279462,
runnerName: "Costa Percy",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 3
},
{
selectionId: 11316530,
runnerName: "Platos Kode",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 4
},
{
selectionId: 11177700,
runnerName: "Parkwarden",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 5
}
]
},
{
marketId: "1.133102480",
marketName: "7f Nov Stks",
totalMatched: 23164.32,
runners: [
{
selectionId: 13428423,
runnerName: "Delph Crescent",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 1
},
{
selectionId: 13079071,
runnerName: "Red Force One",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 2
},
{
selectionId: 13372659,
runnerName: "Porth Swtan",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 3
},
{
selectionId: 12943079,
runnerName: "Zoffalee",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 4
},
{
selectionId: 13373353,
runnerName: "Snooker Jim",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 5
},
{
selectionId: 13763129,
runnerName: "Lineofintelligence",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 6
},
{
selectionId: 13437954,
runnerName: "Surrender",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 7
},
{
selectionId: 13605452,
runnerName: "Cum Spiro Spero",
handicap: 0,
sortPriority: 8
}
]
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
$arr = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
echo $arr['runners'][0]['selectionId'];
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong or even how I can fix this to bring back all selection ID's in an array.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice given.

Comment: Please add this in eval.in

Comment: you can simply use `array_column()` to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use php function [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-column.php)  like this :

> **array array_column ( array $input , mixed $column_key [, mixed
> $index_key = null ] )**
>
> array_column() returns the values from a single column of the input,
> identified by the column_key.
>
> **input** : A multi-dimensional array or an array of objects from which to pull a column of values from.
>
> **column_key** : The column of values to return. This value may be an integer key of the column you wish to retrieve, or it may be a string key name for an associative array or property name.

```
$arr = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
$selectionIds = array_column($records, 'selectionId');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop throw all runners element and then aggregate them in another array.

```
$selectionIds =  array();
for($i=0; $i<count($arr['runners']) ; $i++)
{
array_push($selectionIds, $arr[0]['runners'][$i]->selectionId);
}
var_dump($selectionIds);
```

Comment: Nothing seems to load for that?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$arr[0]['runners'][0]['selectionId']`

Comment: This just still gives me all of the data

Comment: wait, you just want to filter out all selectioIds into a new array?